# a day of major developments with global reach

Tags: word-usage

I understand "with global reach" as "with impact internationally." Am I on the right track?

> We’re wrapping up today’s live US politics coverage for the evening. It’s been **a day of major developments with global reach** here in the United States, as well as sustained infighting within the Republican party over Republicans’ allegiance to Donald Trump and his lies. Here’s an updated summary:

> Source: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/live/2021/may/05/facebook-donald-trump-ban-us-politics-biden-live)

Comment: Yes, it's vague, but I think you have it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. From [wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reach#English)

> **reach**, noun.
> 4: Extent; stretch; expanse; hence, application; influence; result; scope.

So "major developments with global reach" means "big news with worldwide impact."